# Access Site on localhost from a vmware

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have setup a LAMP stack on my home os, and i want to test out some stuff, from vmware. I have windows 10 as my home os, and windows 7 installed on vmware. The site is reacheable on my home os, as 127.0.0.1/site/panel. I have a network type set to `bridged` and `replicate physical network state` checked in vmware settings, but still, when i try to access my site on home ose, i get not found error in ie, on windows 7 inside vmware. The way i connect, is u just use

`ipconfig /all` on my home os ( windows 10 ), i copy the main ipv4 address of my main network adapter, and then paste it inside vmware. How can i setup this kind of connection?

Comment: IP addresses are unique on a subnet, you can't copy your Windows 10 IP address and use it in the Windows 7 VM.  You will want  give your W7 VM a unique IP address that's on the same subnet as W10.  You'll also want to use the W10 IP address to access your site, instead of the 127.0.0.1.  127.0.0.1 is the "home" address of every computer, they all have the same address and only look at their 127.x.x.x IP.   How are IP addresses assigned on your network?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, I think, would be to set up a local only network between your host (home, w10) and the guest vm (w7). Then you will get another interface in your host, you can configure your LAMP to listen in that interface address too and it will be reachable from the VM.

I guess your problem now is that your LAMP stack does not listen (i.e give service) in your external "bridged" interface. 127.0.0.1 is a local only addres.